# XPATH to display based on conditional value

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<chapter>
    <concept>
        <title>*********************</title>
    .
    .
    </concept>

    <sections>
       <title>*******************</title>

</chapter>
```

In the above structure I would like to retrieve text from `<concept><title>` or `<sections><title>`.  i.e. using one xpath condition i need the value with below conditions.

1) if `<concept><title>` is not appeared then `<sections><title>`. vice verso also..

2) Both the title are available there then I want to consider nearst node value. i.e. in above structure "`<sections><title>`" is latest node.

Answer (score 1):

**You want the "nearest" (first) of the two**:

```
(/*/*[self::concept or self::sections]/title)[1]
```

**If you want the "latest" (last) of them, use:**

```
(/*/*[self::concept or self::sections]/title)[last()]
```

---

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
     "(/*/*[self::concept or self::sections]/title)[1]"/>
===============
  <xsl:copy-of select=
     "(/*/*[self::concept or self::sections]/title)[last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<chapter>
    <concept>
        <title>*********Title 1************</title>
    .
    .
    </concept>

    <sections>
       <title>**********Title 2*********</title>
    </sections>

</chapter>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and their results are copied to the output:**

```
<title>*********Title 1************</title>
===============
<title>**********Title 2*********</title>
```

Comment: @hr_117, You are welcome. Yes, this is more efficient than specifying the first node from a union, unless it is known that that XPath processor used, is optimizing such expressions.

Answer (score 0):

So in other words, you just want the last `concept/title` or `sections/title` that occurs under `chapter`?  This XPath should do it (assuming the current context is `chapter`:

```
(concept/title | sections/title)[last()]
```